# How to display the more than one location on google maps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to display the more than one location in my application on google map but I can only show one location how can I show more than one

page.html

```
   <agm-map [latitude]="lat"[longitude]="lng" [zoom]="15"
          [zoomControl]="false">
      <agm-marker *ngFor="let location of tracks" [latitude]="tracks.lat" [longitude]="tracks.lng" [label]="tracks.label"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
```

page.ts

```
    constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {
    this.lat=51.723858
    this.lng=7.895982

  this.tracks = [
            {lat:51.673858, lng: 7.815982,label: 'A'},
            {lat:51.373858, lng: 7.215982,label: 'B'},
        ];

  }
```

Comment: are you using this library? https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `location.lat` instead of `tracks.lat` etc? It looks to me like you're assigning each item in tracks to the variable `location`.

Comment: ahh I want to strangle myself how did I mistake location.lat with tracks.lat but thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're assigning each item in tracks to the variable location you should be using `location.lat` instead of `tracks.lat`.